# Apply multiple filters to dask dataframe

Tags: python, filter, dask, mask

I am trying to filter a large dask dataframe e.g. dd_test with multipe criterias at once.

I have created multiple filters for the dask dd:
e.g.

```
filter1 = ~dd_test['size']<0
filter2 = ~dd_test['obs']<100
filter3 = dd_test['freq']>1
...
filter33 = ~ dd_test['price']<0
```

To apply the filters to the dask datafame, I am executing the following code (which works well):

```
sub_selection = dd_test[filter1][filter2][filter3]...[filter33].compute()
```

However, if certain filters are commented out as they are not needed sometimes, it is very annoying to constantly rewrite the sub_selection to e.g.

```
sub_selelction = dd_test[filter1][filter3][filter9]...[filter27].compute()
```

Thus the idea was to put all active filters into a list before filtering.
The Idea was the following:

Collect all "active" filters in a list via (which works well):

```
selection_list = extend(value for name, value in sorted(locals().items(), key=lambda item: item[0]) if name.startswith('filter'))
```

However, I am not able to apply the list of 22 filters to the dask dataframe.
I have tried several methods without success e.g.:

```
1. sub_selection = dd_test[selection_mask].compute()
2. sub_selection = dd_test[np.logical_and.reduce(selection_mask)].compute()
3. sub_selection = dd_test[pd.Series(np.logical_and.reduce(selection_mask))].compute()
```

1. leads to `ValueError: Item wrong length 22 instead of 0.`
2. leads to `ValueError: Item wrong length 279740 instead of 0.`
3. returns a result but filters are not applied correctly as output is not as expected

Does someone has an idea/solution on how to proceed? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think what I would do is define the filters utilizing element wise AND logic, so that they are combined to a single filter:

```py
filter = (
    (~dd_test['size'] < 0)
    & (~dd_test['obs'] < 100)
    & (dd_test['freq'] > 1)
    ...
    & (~dd_test['price'] < 0)
    )

sub_selection = dd_test[filter].compute()
```

Now you can comment out each filter (except for the first) without any problems

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Totally solved my problem. I was able to use the element wise AND logic on my list of arrays (selection_list).